# Hide Custom Search Total Row in Dashboard

Tags: netsuite

I would like to hide the [Total: x] row in my NetSuite Dashboard when using a Custom Search. Could anyone direct me to the right setting?

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ319.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. When asking a question it is better to *show what research you have done* into your problem and post any *code* or *errors* if it applies.

Answer (score 0):

No setting, but if you repeat the agragate function in a formula numeric or currency, you will not have a summary row for the column